# Angular caching parallel requests

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs

I have defined an interceptor to cache API responses :

```
    if (req.method == 'GET') {
        // return cached object if exists
        const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req) || null;
        if (cachedResponse) {
            return Observable.of(cachedResponse);
        }

        // call api and cache result if doesn't exist
        return next.handle(req).do(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                this.cache.put(req, event)
            }
        });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
```

What is missing here is to don't handle a request if it is pending but wait until the request is ready on cache and return it.

What is the best way to adapt this logic to this issue ?

Comment: Did you take a look at **[the documentation about caching](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching)** ? This might help you

Comment: TY but It doesn't provide an answer about my case

Comment: do you mean in your `do()` function, where will be some problem for parallel requests? Like, 2 requests make with same url, then both request will be sent to server and put to cache?

Comment: @Mavlarn Yes Exactly, I want the second to wait for the first and get it from cache to minimise number of requests to API for better performance

Comment: @absss. There are a "strange thing" in your code. "cache" is Angular 6 (and then Rxjs 6), but you use Rjxs 5 (you're using do, not pipe(tap))

Comment: @Eliseo I use angular 4 with rxjs 5

Comment: `It doesn't provide an answer about my case` I agree, but it gives you every bit of knowledge you need to cache requests. That's why it is a comment, not an answer. If I were you, I'd start reading and implementing what they do. After all, that's the official documentation, they give the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean in your do() function, where will be some problem for parallel requests? Like, 2 requests make with same url, then both request will be sent to server and put to cache？

How about this? Not to put HttpResponse in cache, but to put that Observable object. like this:

```
    if (req.method == 'GET') {
    // return cached object if exists
    const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req) || null;
    if (cachedResponse) {
        return cachedResponse); // it is Observable, even same req in the sam,e time, the second will get a Observable data.
    }

    // call api and cache result if doesn't exist
    const result = next.handle(req);
    this.cache.put(req, result)
    result.do(event => {
        if (event !instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.cache.remove(req) // if it is error, maybe remove?
        }
    return result;
    });
}
return next.handle(req);
```

Comment: Caching Observable Object makes the cache useless, What cache optimises is the distance between observable and response.

Comment: You want to achieve 'pending', so you can only use observable or promise. If you can not add observable object in cache, you need another map to resolve the "2 reqs almost at the same time, which are not in cache" problem. To record the req is in pending.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using cache dict and queue dict with share operator like so :

```
if (req.method == 'GET') {

    // return cached object if exists
    const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req) || null;
    if (cachedResponse) {
        return Observable.of(cachedResponse);
    }

    const pendingResponse = this.queue.get(req) || null;
    if (pendingResponse) {
        return pendingResponse;
    }
    // call api and cache result if doesn't exist
    var obs = next.handle(req).do(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.cache.put(req, event)
            this.queue.clear(req.urlWithParams)
        }
    }).share();
    this.queue.put(req, obs)
    return obs
}
return next.handle(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `shareReplay`, if request in pending status - the same request will be reused, if it completed - the last value will be emitted.

```
if (req.method == 'GET') {

  if (!this.cache.get(req)) {
      const cached = next.handle(req).shareReplay();
      this.cache.put(req, cached);
  }

  return this.cache.get(req);
}
return next.handle(req);
```